# TypeError: insert_results() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ergebnisse'

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

as I´m stuck in OOP i´d be nice if you could help me. I guess its just a little problem either wrong initialization or something with my knowledge of OOP in Python.

So I want to execute a function when I click my button in the Tkinter GUI. This function will pass a dict to a method in my GUI class which adds this in the text widget I have.

I use Python 3.8 and Tkinter is working well.

**Thank you!**

So my code is the following:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from googlesearch import search

def search_():
    url = "werkzeug.de"
    keywords = ["Tauchsäge", "tauchsäge", "tAuchSäge"]
    ergebnisse = {}
    for e in keywords:
        erg = search(e, num_results=10, lang="de")[1:]
        time.sleep(3)
        for i in erg:
            if url in i:
                ind = erg.index(i)
                ergebnisse[e] = ind
    g.insert_results(ergebnisse)


class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui_init()
    def gui_init(self):
        # create tkinter window
        root = tk.Tk()
        # window titel
        root.title("SEO-Ranking Tool")
        # window size and position
        root.geometry("750x600+30+30")
        Label(root, text="URL").grid(row=0, sticky=W,padx=(10, 10))
        Label(root, text="Keywords (Mit komma getrennt)").grid(row=2, sticky=W,padx=(10, 10))
        e1 = Entry(root, width=40)
        e2 = Entry(root, width=40)
        e1.grid(row=1,sticky=W,padx=(10, 10))
        e2.grid(row=3,sticky=W,padx=(10, 10))
        w1 = Button(root, width=34, text="Auswertung", command=search_)
        w1.grid(row=5 ,sticky=W ,padx=(10,10), pady=10)
        excel = 0
        c1 = Checkbutton(root, text="Export to Excel", variable=excel).place(x=300, y=80)
        c2 = Checkbutton(root, text="Blabla", variable=excel).place(x=300, y=50)
        c3 = Checkbutton(root, text="Blabla", variable=excel).place(x=300, y=20)
        self.t1 = Text(root,height=28, width=90)
        self.t1.grid(row=7, padx=(10,10), pady=10)
        root.mainloop()

    def insert_results(self,ergebnisse):
        for i in ergebnisse:
            self.t1.insert(i)
g=GUI()
```

Comment: Where does `search_` belong with the main code.

Comment: Hey @CoolCloud it´s in the same .py file. So its just another function but not in the GUI class.

Comment: Edit and show it's usuage?

Comment: Sure it´s done. @CoolCloud

Comment: Your code has indentation errors which makes it hard for us to understand what your code really looks like.

Comment: no, it's not fixed. Just look at it. Look at the actual question, copy and paste the code into a brand new file, and try to run the file.

Comment: Excuse me, hopefully it´s alright now @BryanOakley

Comment: No, it's not right. The indentation is fixed but you haven't defined `search` and you haven't defined `insert_results`. Regardless, my answer addresses the question being asked. You simply must create an instance of GUI and then call the `insert_results` method on the instance. That's how classes work in python.

Comment: @BryanOakley forgot something again, now. Please check :)
`g = GUI()` and `g.insert_results(ergebnisse)` isn´t working.

Comment: it´s always this error: `TypeError: insert_results() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ergebnisse' `

Comment: Yes, my answer explains why you get that error.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hi, thanks for your time. I don´t know what I´m doing wrong. Did it like you showe´d me in your example. It stills doesn´t find `g`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the instance of `GUI`, not the class itself: `g.insert_results(ergebnisse)`. When you call it on the class, the first argument is passed to `self`, and thus there is no argument being passed as `ergebnisse`

---

Once you solve that problem, you have another problem. Because you call `mainloop` inside a function called by `__init__`, and because `mainloop` never returns, the instance of the class is never fully initialized. Because of that you'll get a `NameError: name 'g' is not defined` since `__init__` never returns which causes `g` to not have been fully created.

The solution to that is to move the call to `mainloop` out of the class, or at least as a separate step after creating the instance of the class.

For example:

```
class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui_init()

    def gui_init(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        ...

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
...
g = GUI()
g.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this already, i get the error: `NameError: name 'g' is not defined` which I did define?

Comment: @grumpyp: I can't answer that. Your code shows you creating it in the global scope. You just need to create it before trying to use a method. This isn't unique to tkinter, it's a fundamental aspect of working with classes. If you need a better answer, you need to provide a better example.

Comment: I don´t know what´s the real mistake in my code. Would be nice if´d provide some code example or a solution to this. (I probably understood something wrong or just try to do it the wrong way)

Comment: @grumpyp: I gave you the solution to the question you asked about. You have to create an instance of `GUI` before you call the `insert_results` method.

Comment: I am doing this by my `g = GUI()` isn´t that right?

Comment: Hi Bryan, would you add the solution to my code please? I actually don´t get it, it´s horrible :D

Comment: Hi @CoolCloud, yes he did but not with my code. Anyways, could you help as well? 
Or is there another solution i could do it with? I know that `global` would work but it´s not that way I should use it.

Comment: @grumpyp Play around with the code, move `mainloop()` outside the class?

Comment: @CoolCloud and Bryan: I´ve put `mainloop()` outside of the class underneath the `g = GUI()` and it works. I don´t really understand why but thank you guys!

Comment: @grumpyp: I explained why in my answer. When it is inside the loop, the object never gets fully initialized because `__init__` is not allowed to complete.